# how to set default color configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento-2.0.7

When I go to a product page, it does not have the default color - but I want to set the default color for a configurable product.

[image]

Comment: you want to select first swatch each time when page load?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I want select product default when page load. Can you help me, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is working for color swatch attribute.

Using below code, first swatch are automatically selected after page load in details page,

you have to override file into your theme,

**app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable */ ?>
<div class="swatch-opt"></div>
<script>
    require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "swatchRenderer"], function ($) {
        $('.swatch-opt').SwatchRenderer({
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
        });

        //for selected option if only one value is exist....
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            //for swatches1
            var swatchLength = $('.swatch-attribute').length;
            if(swatchLength >= 1){
                if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){
                    $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It working but different file 
I edit code this on vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml

Comment: @Rakesh,  when am i trying to capture this events in options.phtml (module-catalog/view/frontend/template/product/view/options.phtml) its not triggered.

Comment: this is the issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181255/magento-2-cant-get-the-selected-color-swatch-value-in-options-phtml-file

Answer (score 6):

A better answer is below. The other answer I couldn't get to work on 2.1.4, the JS was running but it didn't do anything, not sure why? The solution below works perfectly and runs right after the options are rendered which may have been the problem with the other solution for me? It was running too early? :

**Just Override your swatch-renderer.js file into your themee and change `_init()` function same as below: (approx. line 209)**

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js**

```
_init: function () {  
        if (this.options.jsonConfig !== '' && this.options.jsonSwatchConfig !== '') {
            this._sortAttributes(); 
            this._RenderControls();  

            //this is additional code for select first attribute value
            if(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes.length == 1){
                $('.swatch-attribute .swatch-attribute-options div.swatch-option').first().click();
            }

        } else {
            console.log('SwatchRenderer: No input data received');
        }
    },
```

Comment: But this apparently doesn't seem to work on 2.2.1 anymore. Ugh

Comment: Try this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/215803/46716

Answer (score 2):

Create in own theme file **Magento_Swatches/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml**

add the next code like

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $('[data-role="swatch-options"]').on('swatch.initialized', function () {
        $(this).find('.swatch-attribute.color .swatch-option').first().click();
    });
});
```

Comment: The above code didn't work for me.I just add the code to add to cart page for config products and worked.thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Override vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\web\js\swatch-renderer.js 
to your theme
your theme file location will be:
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

change _RenderControls() function

just wrinte below code at the end of this function

```
var swatchLength = $('.swatch-attribute').length;
if(swatchLength >= 1){
    if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("size")){
        $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
    }
}
```

http://prntscr.com/n6qo62