# Magento 2 can't get the selected color swatch value in options.phtml file

Tags: magento-2.1, color-swatches

I am trying to get the selected color swatch value in `options.phtml`

> module-catalog/view/frontend/template/product/view/options.‌​phtml

file with following code.But i am not able to get the value.

[image]

```
<script>
   require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //for swatches1
        $('.swatch-option').click(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    });

});

 </script>
```

Comment: can any one provide the solution

Answer (score 5):

It's working fine When i tried like this.

```
  $('body').on('click', '.swatch-option', function(e) {
       alert("hello");
        var swatchid = $('.swatch-attribute').attr('option-selected');
        var swatchattributeid = $('.swatch-attribute').attr('attribute-id');

    });
```